# JavaFX get mouse position on application start

Tags: java, javafx

There are many eventhandlers for the mouse to retrieve its position, like when the mouse was moved.
But I need the position of the Mouse at the start of the application and I can't seem to find any eventhandler for it.

As an example, i have an Image that should always be at the position of the Mouse, but currently when the Application is started, the Image is in the (0.0, 0.0) coordinate (top left corner) until I move the mouse.
This is not the desired outcome.
The desired outcome should be, that the Image is placed at the position of the mouse directly at start of the Application.
So the question is: How can i get the Position of the Mouse directly at the start of the Application?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps class [javafx.scene.robot.Robot](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/robot/Robot.html) can help?

Comment: Good idea, thanks, but I should have added that I am using javafx 8.

Comment: _Image is in the (0.0, 0.0) coordinate (top left corner) until I move the mouse_ maybe because that's where the mouse is initially :) Register a mouse filter and grab the initial enter - when stuck, provide a  [mcve] please ...

Comment: The position of the mouse relative to what? What if the mouse is not even in the bounds of your application when the application starts?

Answer (score 0):

Well, what is your purpose here? I don't know any methods that you can get this... but you can relocate your image if you have a visible background.
When you start this example the image will relocate from your cursor locate.

```
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(new Image("/image.jpg", 300, 300, false, false));
        Button btn = new Button("Action");

        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane(imageView, btn);
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent;");

        Rectangle2D screen = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, screen.getWidth(), screen.getHeight());
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setMaximized(true);

        scene.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                // Only works if your region does not manage your children.
                imageView.setLayoutX(event.getX());
                imageView.setLayoutY(event.getY());

            }
        });

        stage.show();
```